# PHP compare dates

Tags: php, mysql

ok basically I am trying to compare today date with a database date and determine if today date is > then one of the dates in database. but no matter what date is picked up from datatabase < or > compared to today the result is always true.

Could some one pleas have a look at my code and point out any potential wrongdoings please

PHP

```
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d");

$sql="SELECT enddate FROM campaigns WHERE id=".$data['camp'];
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    if($timestamp > $result){

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('This Workshop Has Expired');</script>";
        exit;
    }else{

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Thank You For Registering');</script>";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your database, how do you store "enddate"? You should be using timestamps for this really, and looking at how you make you `$timestamp` var I'm guessing you dont.

Comment: if($timestamp > $result){  ?? how does php know it is a "date" ? convert to integer using strtotime and then verify. in real life applications use datetime class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($timestamp > $result['enddate']){
```

$result is an array, as called by `$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)`. mysqli_fetch_assoc returns an array with the column name of your row as keys and the content of each field as value.

Comment: owww loool it works but when i did var_dump on each variable $timestamp and $results the numbers looked correct and corresponding both to database and today date, sorr if it is a lame question but could you explain to me why i needed to add $result['enddate']

Answer (score 3):

Try to for example :

```
$var = "2010-01-21 00:00:00.0"//date from DB
strtotime($var);
```

It turns it into a time value, and:

```
time() - strtotime($var);
```

gives you the seconds since `$var`

To check if `$var` has been within the last day try:

```
if((time()-(60*60*24)) < strtotime($var))
```

That's all! :)

Comment: and yes i have tried var_dump both formats looked the same as well as i have tried strtotime the problem seemd to be in my if statment, but thank you for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the "enddate" from your database isn't a number, it's a string.

You should convert it to numbers:

```
$now = time();
$sql="SELECT enddate FROM campaigns WHERE id=".$data['camp'];
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $db = strtotime($result);
    if($now > $db) {
        // expired
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('This Workshop Has Expired'); </script>";
        exit;
    }
    else {
        // not expired
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Thank You For Registering');</script>";
        exit;
    }
}
```